# Better way to create index to optimize query on date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running a query :

```
 select * from users where user_id > 200 and date >= '2020-01-12' and date <= '2020-12-20'.
```

I have created indexes on user_id, date separately. The total no of records are over 2 billion(2.5 to be exact). There is partitioning included in the table , partitioned by the date range. But still the query is taking over a minute to execute.

can anyone suggest better way to use multi-column index  on id, date.

Comment: (1) A standard b-tree index will probably not help very much on this query.  (2) This may return so many rows that no indexes would really help.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include the complete  `create index` statements for all indexes as well and the partition definition of the table (e.g. the `create table`)

Comment: Are "date" and "dates" different columns?   With that many rows, comparing to a date may be a lot faster than comparing to a string.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I am sorry, that was a typo. Its a date coloumn with type date.

Comment: OK, but you compare this column to a string '2020-01-12'.  I would try converting '2020-01-12' to a date.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille actually it takes it as a date without casting it.

Comment: 20 million records is nothing, well that depends on the device or server on which PostgreSQL is running. On a normal consumer grade server, it should take several seconds at max even with no indexes less than a minute. Are you using table partitioning? 20 mil records doesn't qualify for use of partitioned tables.which version of PostgreSQL are you using? please post execution plan of that query.

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy Actually its 2 billion. It was a typo

Comment: What is the granularity of the partitioning?

Comment: @jjanes partitioned on every 3 months.

Comment: How long does it take if you remove the user_id criterium?